# Do we need the surjectivity of a continuous $f: (X, \tau) \to (Y, \rho)$ to get $(X, \tau)$ compact, implies $(Y, \rho)$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I found the following proposition in Morris' "Topology without tears":

> **Proposition:** Let $f: (X, \tau) \to (Y, \rho)$ be a continuous surjective map. Thus, if $(X, \tau)$ is compact, then $(Y, \rho)$ is compact.

In the proof, the author starts from an open covering $\cup_{i \in I} O_i \supseteq Y$ and the compactness of $(X, \tau)$, to get a finite subcover of $(X, \tau)$, which is $\cup_{i \in I} f^{-1} (O_i)$. Then, he proceed with

\begin{align}
Y & =  f(X)\\
& \subseteq f \bigg( \bigcup_{k=1}^n f^{-1} (O_{i_k}) \bigg)\\
& = \bigcup_{k=1}^n f(f^{-1} (O_{i_k}))\\
& = \bigcup_{k=1}^n O_{i_k}.
\end{align}

This last step should come from the fact that $f ( f^{-1} (x)) = x$ thanks to the surjectivity of $f$.

**Question:**
*Do we really need to assume the surjectivity of $f$ to establish the result?*

To me it seems that it is used just for some pedagogical reason to make more explicit the fact that we end up with a finite subcovering of $Y$, thanks to the surjectivity of the function that allows the final step of the chain of equalities. *Am I correct?*

---

**Edit:**
As a matter of fact, I checked Munkres' book on topology, and he does not assume surjectivity to get the same result. Still, I actually buy Clayton's answer below.

So, now I am really puzzled. *What is going on here?*

---

As always any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Of course consider the identity map on any compact subset of a non-compact set.

Comment: The thing is, $f(X)$ will be compact. if f is surjective, $f(X)=Y$

Comment: I write down here the same comment I wrote below Clayton's answer: actually I was compulsively looking at the Munkres, and I found out that theorem 26.5 there is basically the same of this one, but he does not assume surjectivity, just continuity. Now I am puzzled.

Comment: Munkres' theorem 26.5 is "The image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact." It says that if $f\colon X \to Y$ is continuous, and $X$ compact, then $f(X)$ is compact, it says nothing about $Y$ (unless $f$ happens to be surjective).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks a lot. Enlightening comment for a math blind reader (shame on me!). Really, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need surjectivity otherwise an example like $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x$ would show $\Bbb R$ is compact.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. Actually I was compulsively looking at the Munkres, and I find out that theorem 26.5 there is basically the same of this one, but he does not assume surjectivity, just continuity. Now I am puzzled (maybe I should edit my original question accordingly).

Comment: I actually edited the original question after having take a look at Munkres. As I write there, I actually buy your answer, but then I don't see how Munkres' result comes up.

Comment: @Kolmin: I see that Daniel Fischer may have posted a comment enlightening you? If you still need clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But actually, as I wrote, I had bought your answer from the very beginning. Still, when I saw Munkres, that really puzzled me, and Daniel Fischer helped me to see what was really going on.